Im not sure I understand why Django wont let me do asynchronous database transactions
I am trying to create a function that will get_or_create a user record for my discord bot in my django User model as soon as someone runs the !home command - but I am encountering an issue that (as far as I understand) is a normal part of django's existing model wherein it disallows asynchronous database transactions.
I've tried using the built in sync_to_async method but it raises similiar issues. Is there something I can change in my settings file or something that I havent been able to find online that would be able achieve this functionality here?
Here is my home command that is invoked by the command:
@bot.command(name="home", description="Displays the character sheet of your character in Oblivion After you have already created your guy")
async def home_async(ctx):
    user_instance, created = await sync_to_async(User.objects.get_or_create(
        discord_id=discord_user_id,
        defaults={'username': ctx.author.name}
    ))

    if created:
        character = Character.objects.create(name=f"New Character for {ctx.author.name}")
        user_instance.character = character
        user_instance.save()

    view = HomePageView(user=user_instance)
    await ctx.send(f"Welcome {ctx.author.display_name}! Manage your character and inventory here.", view=view)

Currently this is the issue that I am encountering this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/m/ZocPy/OblivionAlchemy/OblivionAlchemy/venv/oblivion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/mnt/m/ZocPy/OblivionAlchemy/OblivionAlchemy/venv/oblivion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/mnt/m/ZocPy/OblivionAlchemy/OblivionAlchemy/venv/oblivion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async


SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context basically states that that you are attempting to perform a synchronous database operation within an asynchronous context, which is not kinda allowed in Django.
use the  Django's sync_to_async decorator to convert synchronous database calls to asynchronous calls. wrap User.objects.get_or_create with sync_to_async, you will be able to execute the database operation asynchronously within your asynchronous command function.
@bot.command(name="home", description="Displays the character sheet of your character in Oblivion After you have already created your guy")
async def home_async(ctx):
    user_instance, created = await sync_to_async(User.objects.get_or_create)(
        discord_id=discord_user_id,
        defaults={'username': ctx.author.name}
    )

    if created:
        character = Character.objects.create(name=f"New Character for {ctx.author.name}")
        user_instance.character = character
        user_instance.save()

    view = HomePageView(user=user_instance)
    await ctx.send(f"Welcome {ctx.author.display_name}! Manage your character and inventory here.", view=view)


I don't see any difference between the code in your answer and the code in the question.

the difference is how the sync_to_async function is utilized:
you wrapped the entire User.objects.get_or_create() method call
--
i wrapped only the User.objects.get_or_create method call, leaving the rest of the function call outside of the wrapper

@WaleOlokunola But there are kwargs that I need to pass in order to make that function work that are ommitted in your answer.

IA Respuesta jajaja

@WaleOlokunola - what are those kwargs or can you explain what you need to have in order to make that function work?
